# After 'rake test' nothing happens in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've just cloned repo from here: https://github.com/netguru-training/workshops.git

And I tried run the tests.
But when I type `rake test` nothing happens. Any warning, error, nothing at all.
I've ran `bundle install` and configure database (in `database.yml`)

What is the problem?
How to run the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this repository use [RSpec](http://rspec.info/). So to launch your test, you should run `rspec`.

Comment: Ohh, what a ridiculous mistake. Great. Thanks!